# Classic ASP start page not found (404) in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

My site/application points to a folder called "site" with all permissions set up.

- In that folder resides "home.asp".
- Default document is "home.asp".

When I go to the domain, I get a "page not found".

If I capture that 404 error in IIS and tell it to redirect to "home.asp", everything works.
The problem with that is I don't want to redirect all 404's to home.asp.
I want the site to default to home.asp and find it.

- Any ideas why this is happening?
- Do I need to do something to the .Net side of things to tell it to
  use the .ASP side of things by default?
- Do I need to create a .aspx default page that redirects to my
  "home.asp"? If so, what do I name that page?

Comment: This is an IIS configuration issue, not a coding issue. This really belongs on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

As Diodeus indicated you should not try to redirect to a default page with a custom 404 error page that redirects, but rather by making sure your "home.asp" is added to the list of default documents within IIS.

This is thus an IIS configuration issue.

For instance for setting up default documents in IIS 6.0 this would be:

1. In IIS Manager, double-click the local computer, right-click the individual Web site folder, and then click Properties.
2. Click the Documents tab.
3. Select the Enable default content page check box.
4. Click Add to add a new default document to the list. (For you this would be your *"home.asp"*)
5. Optional: Click the document you want to remove from the list and click Remove.
6. Click a document from the list and click Move Up or Move down to change the order in which default documents are served to client requests.
7. Click OK.

(From http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Hey AardVark - I appreciate you trying to help. Apparently you didn't read the top part of my message. The first thing I tried was to set up a default home page and that didn't work, which is why I'm setting up custom error pages as a catch-all for now until I can figure this out.

Comment: Which version of IIS are you on?

Comment: 7.5. The problem was fixed by going into the application pool for the site in question and setting .Net version to 2 (from 4).